# How to Show Elements in Succesion, Hide Them, and Then Repeat in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops, show-hide

I want three lines of text to appear in a succession, then hide, and then appear in succession again. So far, I have been able to split the lines into `span` tags and appear in succession, but I can't figure out how to then hide them all at once, and then repeat the animation.

This is my HTML:

```
<span class="flexi-link" id="title-1">Link 1</span>
<span class="flexi-link" id="title-2">Link 2</span>
<span class="flexi-link" id-"title-3">Link 3</span>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#title-1').delay(1000).show(0);
$('#title-2').delay(2000).show(0);
$('#title-3').delay(3000).show(0);
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/TtKnK/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

try this

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.flexi-link').hide();
  $('#title-1').delay(1000).show(0);
  $('#title-2').delay(2000).show(0);
  $('#title-3').delay(3000).show(0);
},"4000");
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/TtKnK/13/)

Comment: @DannyCooper  yes...i posted the link too so you can read more about setInterval....i created this to get you going.. you can adjust the duration as you need ... :)

Comment: Is there a way to make it fire off immediately initially, and only wait 4000 milliseconds on the 2nd loop and those afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

try to do it with setTimeout and callback function

Comment: I'm not familiar with either of those., I'm very new to jQuery. Do you have an example?

Comment: to hide them all: $('#title-3').delay(3000).show(0, function(){$('#title-3').hide();$('#title-2').hide();$('#title-1').hide();});

Answer (score 1):

```
steps = [
    function() {$('#title-1').show(0);},
    function() {$('#title-2').show(0);},
    function() {$('#title-3').show(0);},
    function() {$('.flexi-link').hide(0);},
]

var runStep = function(n) {
    steps[n]();
}

var timedRun = function(interval, step) {
    step = step || 0;
    runStep(step);
    setTimeout(timedRun, interval, interval, (step+1)%steps.length);
}

timedRun(1000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TtKnK/17/

NOTE: I've used functions instead of DOM elements, so you can basically insert any other code you want.
There is surely something in jQuery to make it more, uh, jQuery-esque, I'll leave it up to the experts.

Comment: This just makes the first line hide and doesn't loop anything else.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link (fixed), but the code was right (just a typo, hdie instead of hide)

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well: Can the links hide all at once after they have all appeared in succesion, and then appear in succession again?

Comment: Yea, just change the steps array with whatever effect you'd like to run: http://jsfiddle.net/Dekku/TtKnK/18/

Comment: Just figured that exact solution out on my own with your help. Perfect! Thank you.